# bootstrap 4, height of input vs select are different

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

Can someone show why this happens

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
                <option>select</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When it renders on any browser, bootstrap 4. the height of the input is 3 pixels more than a select.
thanks

Comment: That's normal. Look and feel of the default input elements without styling them is dependent on your browser.

Comment: For Bootstrap it's not normal, it's a bug. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/17194

Answer (score 1):

<strike>As you may know, Bootstrap 4 is still in alpha. This is a known issue: 
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/17194</strike>

This issue has been fixed as of **Bootstrap 4** beta, and therefore works on all the latest versions.

[image]
Also note that `col-xs-6` is simply `col-6` as the `-xs` infix has been removed.

Comment: It seems to be back with 4.0 stable (4.1 is maybe not yet stable). The `<select class="form-control">` is smaller rendered than `<input type="any-text-like" class="form-control">`. There seem to be a work-around for this: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/20809#issuecomment-251771017